# Terminator does not appear in the application switcher and Launcher when using Unity in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, unity, launcher, application-switcher, terminator

I installed the Unity desktop environment in Ubuntu 18.04 and even though everything is working properly, the Terminator app is not being included in the application switcher, making it unreachable by simple pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> back. It does still appear along with other windows when using <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, which is being the way I have to reach it back.

Its icon does not appear in the side navigation bar (Unity Launcher).

It works properly when using the default GNOME desktop environment.

Answer (score 6):

I've been trying to figure this one out for some time. Finally resolved it today by going to Preferences and unchecking the 'Hide from taskbar' option.